# Load Bitmap into memory in Unity using System.Drawing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Using Unity 2017.4.33f1-Personal.

I'm trying to use the [Image.FromFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) method in the System.Drawing namespace to load a Bitmap in a GameObject's logic.  Please note that I am not interested in saving this bmp as an asset or anything like that.  I am only looking to load it into RAM where I can do some calculations.   I have tried the following:

```
var result = Image.FromFile(
    AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(mainImg)
) as Bitmap;
```

But I get the following error:

```
InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Drawing.Image:FromFile (string): IL_0000: ret
```

FYI,

- `mainImg` is a reference to a `Texture2D` resource
- `AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(mainImg)` resolves to `Assets/CustomPackages/SeededConstruction/PuzzleBuilder/Input/main.bmp`

I've also tried a bunch of other goofy things, including getting the absolute path and replacing forward slashes with backslashes like this:

```
var result = Image.FromFile(    
    Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() 
    + "\\" 
    + AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(mainTileset)
    .Replace('/', '\\')
) as Bitmap;
```

In this case, the path resolves to `D:\_Projects\2dGenerator\PlatformGeneration\Assets\CustomPackages\SeededConstruction\PuzzleBuilder\Input\main.bmp`.  However, this returns the same error as above.

What am I doing wrong here?  It seems like this methodology works fine in normal .Net applications, why not in Unity?

Comment: It's not a good idea to start messing about with `System.Drawing` in Unity. Instead, use it's (very extensive and powerful) texture tools. See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.LoadImage.html

Comment: Invalid IL code means the .Net engine itself can't parse whatever function you're calling. That's like catastrophic levels of bad. It has nothing to do with paths or whatever, the .Net assembly you're trying to execute is invalid.

Comment: @3Dave Ah okay that makes sense.  To pivot the question a little bit, what are my options if I have .dll that makes use of System.Drawing and I want to make calls to this .dll from a GameObject?

Comment: The assembly needs to be built against the same framework and version your Unity app is using. However, I've not seen any Unity titles that use `System.Drawing`, as there's typically no reason to do so. If this is a third party assembly, I'd ask what functionality it provides that isn't already available.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question got a downvote.  If the downvoter comes back around, please leave some feedback on why you downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was not any kind of filepath issue.  In order to properly reference System.Drawing in Unity 2017.4.33f1-Personal, I took the following steps:

1. Go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Player.  Change the API Compatability Level from .NET 2.0 Subset to .NET 2.0.
2. Add an `mcs.rsp` to my unity projects root Asset folder.  Open in it in a text editor and on the first line, enter: `-r:System.Drawing.dll`. Save.
3. Close and reopen Unity.